# How to create a new class for a method?

Tags: java, class, methods, program-entry-point

```
package HargaSewaKamar;

import java.io.*;

class Main {
 public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException{
  String nama="",kamar="",jenis="";
  int lama=0,tarif=0;
  
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (System.in));
  
  System.out.println("--**-- SISTEM INFORMASI PERHOTELAN --**--");
  System.out.print("Nama Pelanggan \t\t\t: ");
  nama = br.readLine();
  
  System.out.println("\nPilih Jenis Kamar");
  System.out.println("R. Reguler");
  System.out.println("S. Suite");
  System.out.println("P. President");
  System.out.print("Jenis kamar yang dipesan (R/S/P) \t: ");
  jenis = br.readLine();
  
  System.out.print("\nLama Menginap \t\t\t: ");
  lama = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
  
  if (jenis.equals("R")){
   tarif = lama*300000;
   kamar="Reguler";
  }else if (jenis.equals("S")){
   tarif = lama*500000;
   kamar="Suite";
  }else if (jenis.equals("P")){
   tarif = lama*750000;
   kamar="President";
  }
  
  System.out.println("\n\n---***--- NOTA PEMBAYARAN HOTEL ---***---");
  System.out.println("Nama Pelanggan \t\t\t: " + nama);
  System.out.println("Jenis Kamar \t\t\t: " + kamar);
  System.out.println("Tarif Penginapan \t\t: Rp " + tarif + ",-");
  System.out.println("====================================================");
 }
}
```

I am building a simple program for case study involving hotel pricing. Main.java should be where the user input their data while Hotel.java is where the price category is calculated with the days of stay. This is Main.java, and I wish to put the "if" method in Hotel.java. I did this but the compiler kept giving me 0.

This is Hotel.java

```
public class Hotel{
public static String hitung(String jenis){

String kamar = "";
int tarif=0;
int lama=0;
  if (jenis.equals("R")){
   tarif = lama*300000;   
   kamar="Reguler";
  }else if (jenis.equals("S")){
   tarif = lama*500000;
   kamar="Suite";
  }else if (jenis.equals("P")){
   tarif = lama*750000;
   kamar="President";
}
  return kamar;
}
}
```

Comment: "I did this but the compiler kept giving me 0." Please show the code that's not working - at the moment you haven't shown us Hotel.java, and your code doesn't refer to it. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to change your `Hotel` class to something else. You actually need a class with a constructor accepting `nama`, `jenis` and `lama`. Within this you compute `kamar` and `tarif` as follows (I called it `HotelReservation` because it seems to be more appropriate):

```java
public class HotelReservation {
    private final String nama;
    private final String kamar;
    private final int tarif;

    public HotelReservation(String nama, String jenis, int lama){
        this.nama = nama;

        switch (jenis) {
            case "R":
                tarif = lama * 300000;
                kamar = "Reguler";
                break;
            case "S":
                tarif = lama * 500000;
                kamar = "Suite";
                break;
            case "P":
                tarif = lama * 750000;
                kamar = "President";
                break;
            default:
                tarif = 0;
                kamar = "Invalid";
                break;
        }
    }

    public String getNama() {
        return nama;
    }

    public String getKamar() {
        return kamar;
    }

    public int getTarif() {
        return tarif;
    }
}
```

With this class, you can now create a new Hotel Reservation in your main method given the data from the user:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.println("--**-- SISTEM INFORMASI PERHOTELAN --**--");
        System.out.print("Nama Pelanggan \t\t\t: ");
        String nama = br.readLine();

        System.out.println("\nPilih Jenis Kamar");
        System.out.println("R. Reguler");
        System.out.println("S. Suite");
        System.out.println("P. President");
        System.out.print("Jenis kamar yang dipesan (R/S/P) \t: ");
        String jenis = br.readLine();

        System.out.print("\nLama Menginap \t\t\t: ");
        int lama = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        HotelReservation hotelReservation = new HotelReservation(nama, jenis, lama);

        System.out.println("\n\n---***--- NOTA PEMBAYARAN HOTEL ---***---");
        System.out.println("Nama Pelanggan \t\t\t: " + hotelReservation.getNama());
        System.out.println("Jenis Kamar \t\t\t: " + hotelReservation.getKamar());
        System.out.println("Tarif Penginapan \t\t: Rp " + hotelReservation.getTarif() + ",-");
        System.out.println("====================================================");
    }
}
```